# How to rotate ImageView to current angle?

Tags: android

[image]

How to rotate ImageView to current angle?

Comment: its not a image rotation , Use shapeable image view https://howtodoandroid.com/shapeableimageview-material-components-android/

Comment: Shapeable will crop the image，I want rectangle transform without cropping